# Editing raster and saving with projection and transformation intact

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, gdal, python-script-tool

I am trying to make a custom tool to ArcMap using Python. It is supposed to read in a raster DEM, a point shape file and a distance, and output another raster.

The output raster should be essentially the same as the input one. In the process however, I want to edit some the raster values according to a specified function, namely those that are within the input distance from a point in the point file.

The problem with my script is the saving part. I have two different approaches. Alt 1 is working in the meaning that I get an output file. However is the projection and transformation completely off and I'm not sure how to fix it. Alt 2 is my preferred approach, but i can't figure out how to write my array to a band in the file.
Also I am not sure that the edits gets saved back to the array properly, at least they are not visible in the files I do get.

I'm using ArcMap 10.0 and Python 2.6 on Windows 7.

```
import os, sys, json, osgeo, arcpy, math, arcgisscripting, numpy
from osgeo import gdal, osr, ogr, gdal_array
from osgeo.gdalconst import *

inDEM   = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # .tif
Outlets = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # Point shapefile
outDEM  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) # Path
buffr   = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) # Value

# Register GDAL drivers
gdal.AllRegister()

## Open the DEM
dem    = gdal.Open(inDEM, GA_ReadOnly)
band1d = dem.GetRasterBand(1)
cols   = dem.RasterXSize
rows   = dem.RasterYSize
trf    = dem.GetGeoTransform()
prj    = dem.GetProjection()
driver = dem.GetDriver()

# Get info
band_info  = arcpy.Describe(inDEM + '/Band_1')
nodata_dem = band_info.noDataValue
cellsz     = band_info.meanCellHeight
area       = int(buffr[0])
buffers    = area/cellsz # The area around each chosen cell to use for calculations

# Convert to point file to raster
outlet_raster = 'testraster'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.extent = inDEM
arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion(Outlets, "Enabled", outlet_raster, "MAXIMUM", "", cellsz)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = False


# Convert rasters to arrays (can probably be done in a more memory-efficient way)
outl_arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(outlet_raster, "", cols, rows, None)
nodata_o = outl_arr[0,0] # I know this is not the best way, but not an issue atm
f = numpy.argwhere(outl_arr != nodata_o)

dem_arr  = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(inDEM, "", cols, rows, None)


# Create slope array
slope = []
x_list = numpy.arange(0,5,.01)
for i in x_list:
    slope.append(-math.exp(-i))
length = len(slope)

# Make modifications
non = []
for i in range(len(f)): 
    index = f[i]
    if dem_arr[index[0], index[1]] != nodata_dem:
        r_low = index[0] - buffers
        r_up  = index[0] + buffers +1
        c_low = index[1] - buffers
        c_up  = index[1] + buffers +1
        data  = dem_arr[r_low:r_up, c_low:c_up]
        dim  = math.sqrt(numpy.size(data))
        n1 = math.floor(dim/2)
        for j1 in range(dim):
            for j2 in range(dim):
                n2 = data[j1,j2]
                dist = math.sqrt((n1-j1)**2 + (n1-j2)**2)*cellsz 
                decr = length * dist / area
                if decr < length and decr != 0 and n2 != nodata_dem:
                    data[j1,j2] = n2 + slope[int(math.floor(decr))]
                elif decr == 0:
                    data[j1,j2] = n2 + slope[0]
                elif decr == length:
                   data[j1,j2] = n2 + slope[-1]
        dem_arr[r_low:r_up, c_low:c_up] = data  
    else:
        non.append(f[i])

# Trying to save the changes Alt 1.
newraster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(dem_arr, "", inDEM, "", nodata_dem)
newraster.save(outDEM)

# Trying to save Alt 2.
newdem = driver.Create(outDEM, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
newdem.SetGeoTransform(trf)
newdem.SetProjection(prj)
newband = newdem.GetRasterBand(1)
newband.WriteArray(dem_arr) #
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem that you might be having with Alt 1 is that the second parameter in arcpy.NumpyArrayToRaster() should be an point object with the lower left coordinates of your output raster. You might try something like this:

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(inDEM)
xmin = desc.extent.xmin
ymin = desc.extent.ymin
cellwidth = desc.meanCellWidth
cellheight = desc.meanCellHeight
nodata = desc.noDataValue
sr = desc.SpatialReference

newraster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(dem_arr, arcpy.Point(xmin, ymin), cellwidth, cellheight, nodata)

arcpy.DefineProjection_management(newraster, sr)
newraster.save(outDEM)
```

Regarding Alt 2, setting your nodata value and calculating statistics might help you see your outputs.

```
newband.SetNoDataValue(nodata_dem)
newband.GetStatistics(0, 1)
dem = None
```